# NUnit result are different in debug and release

Tags: c#, unit-testing, binding, nunit, tracelistener

I can't get rid of this problem. It's very strage, when I try to run my NUnit test in Debug mode, I get the expected result but when I just run it normally, the result is Wrong.

What i'm trying to do is detect Binding errors. Here is a sample

```
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
public class BindingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void T1_BindingErrorsExpected()
    {
        string error = null;
        using (var listener = new ObservableTraceListener())
        {
            listener.TraceCatched += s => error = s;

            TextBlock myText = new TextBlock();
            UserControl control = new UserControl();
            Binding myBinding = new Binding("BadBinding");
            myBinding.Source = control;
            myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, myBinding);
        }
        Assert.IsNotNull(error);
    }
}
```

And the ObservableTraceListener

```
public sealed class ObservableTraceListener : DefaultTraceListener
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _Builder = new StringBuilder();
    public ObservableTraceListener()
    {
        PresentationTraceListener.Add(SourceLevels.Error, this);
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Flush();
        Close();
        PresentationTraceListener.Remove(this);
        base.Dispose();
    }   

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        _Builder.Append(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Write(message);

        if (TraceCatched != null)
            TraceCatched(_Builder.ToString());

        _Builder.Clear();
    }

    public event Action<string> TraceCatched;
}


public static class PresentationTraceListener
{
    public static void Add(SourceLevels level, TraceListener trace)
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(trace);
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = level;
        PresentationTraceSources.ResourceDictionarySource.Listeners.Add(trace);
        PresentationTraceSources.ResourceDictionarySource.Switch.Level = level;
    }

    public static void Remove(TraceListener trace)
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Remove(trace);
        PresentationTraceSources.ResourceDictionarySource.Listeners.Remove(trace);
    }
}
```

Result in debug -> Fail (What I expect)

Result in Run-> Success (Not what expected)

Comment: I'm going to guess this has to do with side effects from the DefaultTraceListener, which is trying to call an old fashion trace  mechanism (OutputDebugString). What was the motivation for using that as the base class instead of deriving from TraceListener?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I'll try implementing traceListener tomorrow and I will give you feedback

Comment: I just tested with `public sealed class ObservableTraceListener : TraceListener` instead of `public sealed class ObservableTraceListener : DefaultTraceListener` and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: i just updated my example and when i'm in debug mode, the call to TraceListner is thrown by the myText.SetBinding(). In run mode, the setBinding method doestn't throw. If this can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks MatthewMartin but I found the solution looking at https://github.com/bblanchon/WpfBindingErrors

The probem was my `ObservableTraceListener`.

I needed to add a static constructor calling `PresentationTraceSources.Refresh()` to get it works correctly. As said in MSDN doc, it `Refreshes trace sources, by forcing the app.config file to be re-read`. So, some initialization was just done when I started the test in "debug" mode, which probably caused the app.config file to be read.

MSDN doc -> PresentationTraceSources.Refresh() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.refresh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here is my final `ObservableTraceListener` and the `PresentationTraceListener` is the same as the one in the question

```
public sealed class ObservableTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _Builder = new StringBuilder();


    static ObservableTraceListener()
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
    }

    public ObservableTraceListener()
    {
        PresentationTraceListener.Add(SourceLevels.Error, this);
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Flush();
        Close();
        PresentationTraceListener.Remove(this);
        base.Dispose();
    }   

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        _Builder.Append(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _Builder.Append(message);

        if (TraceCatched != null)
            TraceCatched(_Builder.ToString());

        _Builder.Clear();
    }

    public event Action<string> TraceCatched;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer because a comment would be too small to hold what I want to say...

There is no reference to PresentationTraceListener on the internet-- how it treats the TraceListener is important because AFAIK the PresentationTraceListener is what calls the Write/WriteLine methods of the TraceListener (possibly indirectly via TraceSource)

This code below compiles in a brand new project. If I Write(x), I get null, if I writeLine(x), I get a value. Generally when you write a custom TraceListener, you redirect all the overloads to a single method so that they all behave the same (Write and WriteLine should be identical except WriteLine tacks a newline onto the message for the caller.)

Another observation is that System.Diagnostics trace is a quirky logging library whose main advantage is that it is always available even when there is some barrier to using 3rd party libraries. System.Diagnostics trace really wants you to register a TraceSwitch, TraceListener in your app.config or web.config and use that to enable & disable trace. It also requires the the TRACE flag be registered (in the same way the DEBUG flag gets registered, in the project properities-- by default TRACE is defined for DEBUG and RELEASE)

```
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
public class BindingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void T1_BindingErrorsExpected()
    {
        string error = null;
        using (var listener = new ObservableTraceListener())
        {
            listener.TraceCatched += s => error = s;

            //TextBlock myText = new TextBlock();
            //UserControl control = new UserControl();
            //Binding myBinding = new Binding("BadBinding");
            //myBinding.Source = control;
            //myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, myBinding);
            PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error,0, "Hello World!");    
        }
        Assert.IsNotNull(error);
        Console.WriteLine(error);

    }
}

public sealed class ObservableTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _Builder = new StringBuilder();
    public ObservableTraceListener()
    {
        //PresentationTraceListener.Add(SourceLevels.Error, this);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Flush();
        Close();
        //PresentationTraceListener.Remove(this);
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        _Builder.Append(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Write(message);

        if (TraceCatched != null)
            TraceCatched(_Builder.ToString());

        _Builder.Clear();
    }

    public event Action<string> TraceCatched;
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry PresentationTraceListener is my custom class. I edit my post

Comment: Okay, PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource is an ordinary TraceSource and when called directly acts fine, both in DEBUG and RELEASE on my machine.

I did notice that "error" only holds the most recent value, so if Binding(), .Source, .SetBinding() all wrote to the TraceSource (including possible blank lines), you might not see the message you expect.) 

Also, try logging at the Verbose level, maybe it's being recorded as a Warning in release mode. My next step would be to disassemble that Binding object and see how it is calling the TraceSource.

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution and posted it! i know error just hold the last binding error but It was just a simplified sample! In my procject I use a stringBuilder with append() method to hold all the binding error, and I use `Assert.That(sb.ToString(), Is.Empty, sb.ToString())` ... if this can help someone!